# iOS - singleton is not working as supposed in delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, singleton

Currently I'm working on an app that uses four protocols for communication between classes. Three are working fine, but one is still not working. I've set it up same as the others but the delegate is always losing its ID. I'm quite new to Objective-C so I can't get to the bottom of it. Here is what I did:

I have a MainViewController.h with the delegate

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <PlayerProtocol> player;
```

and a MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[Interface sharedInstance] Init];
    NSLog(@"Player ID: %@", _player);
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad: %@", self);
}

- (void)sedPlayer:(id) pointer{ //sed is no typo!
    _player = pointer;
    NSLog(@"sedPlayer ID: %@", _player);
    NSLog(@"sedPlayer: %@", self);
}

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

In the Interface.m (NSObject)

```
- (void)Init {
    [[MainViewController sharedInstance] sedPlayer:self];
}
```

And of course a protocol.h but this is not of interest as the delegate does the trouble! When I run the code I get the following output on the console:

```
sedPlayer ID: <Interface: 0x1700ab2e0>
sedPlayer: <MainViewController: 0x100406e30>
Player ID: (null)
viewDidLoad: <MainViewController: 0x100409550>
```

So it is obvious that the singleton is not working as the instance of the MainViewcontroller is different. For the singleton I'm using the dispatch_once standard method as I do with the other protocols that work fine. ARC is turned on. Does anyone has a clue what is wrong here and why the singleton is not working?

Comment: first you should use `assign` replace of `strong`, when you using a `delegate`:`@property (strong, nonatomic) id <PlayerProtocol> player`, second, please post your whole code in your question, we can find where is the issue.

Comment: ^ No, use `weak` instead of `assign`. `assign` will require you to `nil` out references to that object when it gets deallocated or else you'll get a crash when you send a message to the (now deallocated) object.

Comment: @Hecot are you sure `[MainViewController sharedInstance]` is the same instance of `MainViewController` as `viewDidLoad` is called from?

Comment: @aircraft: I've used weak before, but also assign makes no difference.

Comment: @AdamPro13 I've added two NSLog outputs and found that the instance is different and it seams the singleton is not working as supposed. I added some more code above, maybe you can help?

Comment: using singletons is a hint that your application architecture is flawed, using view controller singletons sounds outright wrong to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I think you ended up with two instances of the `MainViewController`. The first one, I assume, is created when navigating to the screen associated with `MainViewController`. The second one is created when you call `[MainViewController sharedInstance]` in `Interface.m`.

As the ViewController view is lazy loaded ("View controllers load their views lazily. Accessing the view property for the first time loads or creates the view controller’s views." from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller) under ViewManagement), you see the `viewDidLoad: <MainViewController: 0x100409550>` log only once, when the first `MainViewController` gets navigated to and loads up the view.

Here's my suggestion:

Since you do the `Interface` initializing in the `- (void)viewDidLoad`, you might as well set `self.player = [Interface sharedInstance]`.

The code would look something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.player = [Interface sharedInstance];
    NSLog(@"Player ID: %@", _player);
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad: %@", self);
}
```

You should also get rid of `- (void)sedPlayer:(id) pointer` and `+ (instancetype)sharedInstance` in your `MainViewController`. It is never a good idea to have a ViewController singleton, since you might end up messing up the navigation or having multiple states of it.

For a more in-depth article on avoiding singletons, you can check [objc.io Avoiding Singleton Abuse](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/singletons/)